# Network Setting in Docker Compose file, to Join Wordpress Containers Together

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm hosting 2 wordpress website on my VPS, and I'm using Nginx Proxy Manager to proxy them.
I use Docker network connect to join NPM & 2 Wordpress containers together to make them work, but after reload or restart docker the networks between them is broken. (Is that because I use systemctl restart docker? or compose down & up ?)
So now I decide to create a new network in docker called bridge_default, and put this network in docker compose file so I don't have to connect those containers together to make them work every time.
But now I don't know where is wrong in docker compose file, Can any one tell me how to put networks in docker compose file correctly?

```
version: "3"
# Defines which compose version to use
services:
  # Services line define which Docker images to run. In this case, it will be MySQL server and WordPr>  db:
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # image: mysql:5.7 indicates the MySQL database container image from Docker Hub used in this inst>    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PassWord#123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PassWord#123
      # Previous four lines define the main variables needed for the MySQL container to work: databas>
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    # Restart line controls the restart mode, meaning if the container stops running for any reason, >    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PassWord#123
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
# Similar to MySQL image variables, the last four lines define the main variables needed for the Word>    volumes:
      ["./wordpress:/var/www/html"]
volumes:
  mysql: {}
networks:
 default: bridge_default
```

[Docker compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKsUO.png) 

[Docker networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTlPT.png)

Can any one tell me how to put networks in docker compose file correctly?

Comment: try "network_mode: bridge_default" in your service descriptions (same hierarchy placement as "image" or "environment")

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now I've join the wordpress & NPM containers all to bridge_default, but now two wordpress website says a databse error:'Error establishing a database connection'. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of a working named network in docker-compose v2.15.1

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  first-named-service:
    image: my-image-1:latest
    networks:
      - my-network-1
  second-named-service:
    image: my-image-2:latest
    networks:
      - my-network-1

networks:
  my-network-1:
```

With this configuration, the 2 services share a named network and can access each other by service name.

For example, if "second-named-service" were a server hosting files on port 8888 I could access those files from "first-named-service" by doing something like sending an http request to http://second-named-service:8888/my-file

So for your specific case, give a name to the first service, otherwise you can't access it from the second one.